# How to get class names of elements under one id by getElementById in Javacscript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

How to get class names of elements which are under one id name by getElementById?

I tried to

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><div id="navTabs" class="tab1">1</div></li>
<li><div id="navTabs" class="tab2">2</div></li>
<li><div id="navTabs" class="tab3">1</div></li>
<li><div id="navTabs" class="tab4">2</div></li>
</ul>
```

Javscript

```
document.getElementById("navTabs").onclick = function tab_click() {
assignedTabName = document.getElementById("navTabs").className;
alert(assignedTabName);
}
```

It doesn't work. HTML states that use separate id and class names with every objects. I am trying to put tab content box with one id name and separate class names for each tabs.

It seems to be getting errors for **HTML grammars** for object names. But, how to use same id name and separate class names by only javascript, **not jquery**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess javascript is still under development to manage HTML type language and it does not have good functions provided for managing list menu materials rather than using jquery now.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

`getElementById` returns a *single* Element (or `null` if there aren't any that match).

An ID *must* be unique in a document. You are trying to process something that isn't HTML.

Classes are used to mark an element as a member of a group. You seem to have them and IDs backwards.

---

You could probably hack around it by using `querySelectorAll` and an attribute selector:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id=navTabs]');
```

… but you should fix the markup instead.

Comment: In HTML, it is stated that id and class names have to be unique, but for list items or some data types. I will try.

Comment: "but for list items or some data types" — No, there are no exceptions to the "IDs must be unique in a document" rule.

Comment: When you use `<div> or <ul>` tab menu, it will be same id but different classes like the one I put on. Is there any way around that I can put id for the menu category and different class names for selections. I think it was UL or DIV table exceptions.

Comment: @john3825 — "it will be same id but different classes like the one I put on" — **No**, that is wrong. The classes should be the same, the ids must be unique.

Comment: @john3825 — "Is there any way around that" — Yes, it in my original answer, it is still a stupid and wrong thing to do.

Comment: `id="navTabs" class="tab#"` #=number, will generate good list from HTML. It is id navTabs of subclass tab# for the list for example. Or should I subclass ids for menu selections? ex. Id=navTabs and downer level id=tab#. For making better and simpler HTML text than scripts messed slower site.

Comment: @john3825 — I have no idea what you are trying to ask there, but classes (in HTML and CSS terms) have nothing to do with object oriented programming so the term "subclass" make no sense.

Comment: ID=navTabs and selections of tabs ID=tabs for example. What is the best way to reference tab or menu items under one id from simple javascript? I was trying to use jquery. But, it can not be run under some restricted sites. So, I am trying to make a "tabs content box" for larger volume than 10 tabs with simple javascript. The site I am using 'smarty' templete engine which restricts jquery uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns a single element or null if it doesn't exist.

IDs has to be unique.

If you're using jQuery you can listen on the parent `<ul>` :

```
$('ul').on('click', 'a', function() {
    e.preventDefault(); //don't follow the link
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

//edit:
I saw the **not jQuery** part now, check querySelectorAll like @Quentin said, however you really should fix your markup instead.